# how to solve the ereg function deprecated error

Tags: php, deprecated, ereg

I am working with SEO PHP scripts and I am just following Google SEO scripts. When I used the search terms I got an error like the following:

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 3876

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 3896

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 1451
```

How should I remove that error function? Is there any need to use a library?

Comment: You should use preg_* functions . Check if there is a new version of the nusoap library which doesn't use the deprecated functions. Or, to take an easy way out, you can suppress error messages of 'Deprecated' type by changing the error_reporting arguments.

Comment: **FATAL ERROR: Not [using the Search Function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ereg+deprecated) is deprecated.**

Comment: @Iavan - Stack Overflow, strives to be a technical resource akin to encyclopedias. As such, the writing style should preclude pleasantries and formalities such as "hello", "thank you", "help me", etc., with exactly the same reasoning that "hope this helps" isn't at the bottom of any Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eregi() function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

you can use preg_match().

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

> Note:
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension is deprecated in favor of the [PCRE extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). Calling this function will issue an `E_DEPRECATED` notice. See the [list of differences](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) for help on converting to PCRE.

You need to convert every use of `ereg*` to an [equivalent function](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) of the [`preg_*` family](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). Or, as [@Srisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495848/srisa) rightly points out, look for an updated version of the library/script in question.

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting( 0 ) ;`
That's how you can eliminate the symptoms, but to cure the disease you just shouldn't use POSIX regular expressions, change them to PCRE

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check this brunch http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoapforphp53/
it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Change `ereg()` to `mb_ereg.hope` which fixes your error. Good luck!