# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated, how to solve this error?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using this php code. but it's giving error

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fuel\emailcheck.php on
>   line 7

```
<?
include_once("mastersecure.php");
$emailcheck=$_POST["member_name"];
function isValidEmail($email){
      $pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";

      if (eregi($pattern, $email)){
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }   
   }
  if (!isValidEmail($_POST['member_name'])){
                echo "The email is invalid!";
            }
    else
     {
       $query="select email from fuel where email='$_POST[member_name]'";
       $res=mysql_query($query);
       $rowcount=mysql_num_rows($res);
       if($rowcount!=0)
       { echo "This mail is already exits"; }
     }      
?>
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve the ereg function deprecated error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825205/how-to-solve-the-ereg-function-deprecated-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Email Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906608/php-email-validation)

Comment: *(related)* [Does FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL make a string safe for insertion in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154685/does-filter-validate-email-make-a-string-safe-for-insertion-in-database)

Comment: *(related)* [XKCD SQL injection - please explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<?
include_once("mastersecure.php");
$emailcheck=$_POST["member_name"];
function isValidEmail($email){
      $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i";

      if (preg_match($pattern, $email)){
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }   
   }
  if (!isValidEmail($_POST['member_name'])){
                echo "The email is invalid!";
            }
    else
     {
       $query="select email from fuel where email='$_POST[member_name]'";
       $res=mysql_query($query);
       $rowcount=mysql_num_rows($res);
       if($rowcount!=0)
       { echo "This mail is already exits"; }
     }      
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

Comment: Do I just need to replace `eregi($pattern, $email))` with `preg_match($pattern, $email))`?

Comment: not very helpful answer, because pattern should be changed too. however, it seems not a programmer but user question.

Comment: Just to let you know.. You regex itself is faulty.. try validating an email address like me@domain.info :)

Comment: @amitchd - Please tell me , how to fix that? how to make regex compatible for any email with any top level domain

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: replace `{2,3}` by `{2,5}` in your pattern

Comment: And then there's `.museum`... trying to check TLDs in regex is a flawed concept, and the username part of the expression is also too restrictive.